# Infralution VirtualTree leaking GDI+ Objects when Icons are set in GetRowData event handler

Tags: c#

We have seen what appears to be GDI Object leakage when the Infralution VirtualTree control assigns Icons in the GetRowData event.  The VirtualTree is contained in a control that is contained within a TabControl.  Tabbing away and back to the tree results in the "GDI Objects" counter in Task Manager to continually increment.  After commenting out the GetRowData event (basically eliminating the Icons), switching back and forth to this tab results in no increase in GDI Object count.

This has become an issue with our application as several instances of it run at once on client machines, and under load our application crashes due to errors in GDI Object creation.

Is there anyway to pre-empt a cleanup on the Tree control (besides disposing it?).  I looked into moving the tree initialization code out of the designer so that I could dispose/re-initialize it each time, but am worried at the impact on ability to design the overall control.

Answer (score 1):

Can we see the code for GetRowData?  If this function allocates the GDI objects for the icons, then the solution is to re-use icons rather than re-creating them every time.